# Cannot Click on the I agree button with Imacros

Tags: imacros

To create gmail account with imacros i have completed everything but getting problem only with the privacy and terms agreement form, to be able to click on the agree button I have to scroll down to the bottom of the form. But I can't scroll with imacros:

[image: Privacy Dialog]

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=ID:iagreebutton
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on IE

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:createaccount ATTR=NAME:submitbutton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:tos-text-div
URL GOTO=javascript:twindow.scrollBy(0,50);
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=ID:iagreebutton
```